# Zipf Distribution based number generation

Tags: random, statistics, distribution, zipf

I want to generate a popularity distribution for a small data set, which should follow `Zipf` law.

The available parameters are:
Total number of viewers : 1 Million
Total number of videos  : 36

I want to associate total number of viewers to each video according to `Zipf` law. For instance, how many of viewers will watch video1, video2 .. and so on.
Can anyone please tell me the formula or methodology?

Comment: Your parameters seem strange. Please, explain they better. Also, explain what do you mean with the Zipf Law. On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf's_law, there are plenty of formulas, why they do not fit to you? Do you do not understand they? What you do not understand?

Comment: @addons_zz
I want to generate a synthetic workload, where I have 36 videos, and around 1 million viewers. Now how many times each video is viewed according to zipf law is what I want to find. 
So if N = 1 Million (means  there are 1 million viewers)
k= 1..30, mean K1 be the rank of video V1 and so on .. 
then what would be the s ??? 
as mentioned in the wikipedia 

    N be the number of elements;
    k be their rank;
    **s be the value of the exponent characterizing the distribution.**

How can I calculate or choose "s" in this scenario ??

Comment: Can you edit the question providing these new information, instead of adding them at once as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on Zipf's law includes a few descriptions of the distribution, including some ways to calculate it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law

The first equation under the *Theoretical review* section might help. Using this, we can write a short Python script to associate the total number of viewers for each of 36 videos:

```
N_elements = 1000000
video_exponent = 1

distribution_sum = 0
total_viewers = 0


# First, add up the relative number of viewers across all 36 movie ranks
for k_rank in range(1,36):

    sum = 0
    for n in range(1, N_elements):
        sum = sum + 1/(n**video_exponent)

    distribution_sum = distribution_sum + (1/(k_rank**video_exponent))/sum


# Next, distribute the number of viewers so that the total comes to 1,000,000
print("Movie Rank | # of Viewers")
for k_rank in range(1,36):

    sum = 0
    for n in range(1, N_elements):
        sum = sum + 1/(n**video_exponent)

    viewers_at_k_rank = round((N_elements/(k_rank**video_exponent))/(sum * distribution_sum))

    print(k_rank, end="|")
    print(viewers_at_k_rank)

    total_viewers = total_viewers + viewers_at_k_rank


print("\nSum of all viewers accounted for so far, to make sure we're at 1,000,000")
print(total_viewers)
```

The result adds up to 1,000,002 viewers, but that's not a big deal. Why isn't it a big deal, you ask? It seems that while many different *things* follow a general Zipfian distribution, they tend to be slightly different based on what type of *thing* it is. The **video_exponent** variable can be adjusted so that the Zipfian distribution simulated above can more closely match actual *video* statistics. The difference is usually much greater than 2 in 1,000,000.

You can get an idea of what the real-world **video_exponent** is by finding some real ranked videos, and adjusting **video_exponent** and **N_elements** until the code matches the real numbers. Then, reset **N_elements** back to 1,000,000, and you'll have a realistic video-watching data set.

Comment: Interesting but there's no randomness in your answer.

Comment: Randomness, huh? Just execute Von Neumann's coin flip algo on some qubits a bunch of times. Eventually you'll hit randomness bedrock, and the universe will burp out a seg fault in appreciation of your discovery.

Comment: OP is asking to generate a random distribution. Your answer is deterministic (as opposed to deterministically pseudorandom) and would not pass statistical tests for randomness.